# Make Asynchronous RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

With springboot is there a way to make the default crud methods provided by the @RepositoryRestResource annotation asynchronous(with mongodb)? Meaning for example when i make 1000 save or find method(database) request, the thread doesnt wait for every single request to complete, it makes a new thread for each save() request, instead of executing each database request sequentially on one thread.

Comment: Why would you think that helps? Your servlet container is already multi threaded and requests are handled concurrently. The `RepositoryRestResource` doesn't block a single thread it can handle them concurrently.

Comment: i mean, the save() or findAll() method of the Repository does block on one thread.

Comment: It waits for a return, true, but it doesn't block all the other threads. Each incoming HTTP request is already handled in its own thread.

Comment: It blocks each next Repository methods, so they are executed sequentially.

Comment: No they aren't. Tomcat can handle, by default, 200 concurrent requests, each can call the same method at the same time. If you call 3 methods in the same thread in sequence, then yes it will obviously block that single thread and execute those calls sequentially.

Comment: I see, i wrote it confusingly. So when one Http Request calls 1000 save() methods of the repository, then it blocks one the same thread, and thats my problem.(edited)

Comment: Then please re-write your question. Also making 1000 threads just for save methods is overkill (`Thread` is a relative heavy object to create and maintain). Instead use a `TaskExecutor` and use `supplyAsync` or if you don't care about the result `runAsync` for each call to save. Or use a `CompletableFuture` in which you use a `TaskExecutor` to schedule tasks, then join all of them into a single one and wait for it to finish.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really make sense nor makes it clearer.